# Polymorphic Analysis

Tags: malware, reverse-engineering

I'm a beginner at malware analysis. For my research studies, I have to identify polymorphic malware based from experiments. I would like to know if there are any guides showing how to analyze the code (assembly language) of polymorphic malware using ollydbg (or other tools) to see where it started to mutate?

Comment: Unfortunately calls for links/guides/etc. are off-topic

Answer (score 0):

In the following articles, the decryption key of the decryption loop is mutated:

https://n1ps.wordpress.com/2008/09/14/w32virut-analysis/
https://n1ps.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/w32virut-analysis-part-2/

There's no universal guide to find all these kinds of mutations with OllyDbg or other tools but you could try to find Crypto code where there're lots of arithmetic/logic instructions as a tip to start your mutation digging journey.